# Can I access Facebook's friend list and other information using AWS Cognito?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

We are analyzing AWS Cognito adoption as our authentication service.

We use social network data in some ML models after the user is logged in, if he or she allowed us to.

The doubt is: if the user signs up using Facebook, can I ask for custom information (friends list, list of posts, etc.) using Cognito? If yes, how would I access this information later?

We searched everywhere but can't find anywhere talking about it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For anyone arriving by Google: the Cognito SDKs return a response that contains the API key for that user on Facebook. Check it out in the [Javascript SDK](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/facebook.html):

```
FB.login(function (response) {

  // Check if the user logged in successfully.
  if (response.authResponse) {

    console.log('You are now logged in.');

    // Add the Facebook access token to the Cognito credentials login map.
    AWS.config.credentials = new AWS.CognitoIdentityCredentials({
      IdentityPoolId: 'IDENTITY_POOL_ID',
      Logins: {
        'graph.facebook.com': response.authResponse.accessToken
      }
    });

    // Obtain AWS credentials
    AWS.config.credentials.get(function(){
        // Access AWS resources here.
    });

  } else {
    console.log('There was a problem logging you in.');
  }

});
```

`response.authResponse.accessToken` is the token you can use in the [Facebook API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/web). You set the permissions you need from this user in your app in Facebook's developer console. Then, you can proceed to make API calls to Facebook.